How to make multiple relationships between two tables in Libreoffice Base
I have a table with for a event and another table with a list of controls. The table with events can have multiple controls so I want to link the controls table to multiple values on the event table. Is this possible in Libreoffice Base?
Example:
I have 1 event and 2 controls for that event, so in my form entry for that event I want to be able to select 2 controls for entry and have these both connected to the event. These controls will both be stored in the same table.

Are you asking how to program a macro for this? Otherwise, where is the software development aspect?
